# Convert 2D numpy.ndarray to pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have a pretty big `numpy.ndarray`. Its basically an array of arrays. I want to convert it to a `pandas.DataFrame`. What I want to do is in the code below

```
from pandas import DataFrame

cache1 = DataFrame([{'id1': 'ABC1234'}, {'id1': 'NCMN7838'}])
cache2 = DataFrame([{'id2': 3276827}, {'id2': 98567498}, {'id2': 38472837}])

ndarr = [[4.3, 5.6, 6.7], [3.2, 4.5, 2.1]]
arr = []
for idx, i in enumerate(ndarr):
    id1 = cache1.ix[idx].id1
    for idx2, val in enumerate(i):
        id2 = cache2.ix[idx2].id2
        if val > 0:
            arr.append(dict(id1=id1, id2=id2, value=val))
df = DataFrame(arr)
print(df.head())
```

I am mapping the index of the outer array and the inner array to index of two `DataFrame`s to get certain IDs.
`cache1` and `cache2` are `pandas.DataFrame`. Each has `~100k` rows.

This takes really really long, like a few hours to complete. 
Is there some way I can speed it up?

Comment: I copied the code as is. `cache1['A']` was an internal thing (basically a key to the cache), so maybe was confusing. I corrected it now.

Comment: The last entry in `cache2`, shouldn't it be `{'id2': 38472837}` instead of `{'id': 38472837}`?

Comment: @CTZhu: you're almost certainly right.

Comment: @DSM, in that case maybe the `multiindex` will be an suitable approach, let's see what the OP says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your `ndarr`, if expressed as a 2d `np.array`, always has the shape of `n,m`, where `n` is the length of `cache1.id1` and `m` is the length of `cache2.id2`. And the last entry in cache2, should be `{'id2': 38472837}` instead of `{'id': 38472837}`. If so, the following simple solution may be all what is needed:

```
In [30]:

df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(ndarr).ravel(),
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cache1.id1.values, cache2.id2.values],names=['idx1', 'idx2']),
             columns=['val'])
In [33]:

print df.reset_index()
       idx1      idx2  val
0   ABC1234   3276827  4.3
1   ABC1234  98567498  5.6
2   ABC1234  38472837  6.7
3  NCMN7838   3276827  3.2
4  NCMN7838  98567498  4.5
5  NCMN7838  38472837  2.1

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

Actually, I also think, that keep it having the `MultiIndex` may be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
ndarr = np.asarray(ndarr) # if ndarr is actually an array, skip this
fast_df = pd.DataFrame({"value": ndarr.ravel()})
i1, i2 = [i.ravel() for i in np.indices(ndarr.shape)]
fast_df["id1"] = cache1["id1"].loc[i1].values
fast_df["id2"] = cache2["id2"].loc[i2].values
```

which gives

```
>>> fast_df
   value       id1       id2
0    4.3   ABC1234   3276827
1    5.6   ABC1234  98567498
2    6.7   ABC1234       NaN
3    3.2  NCMN7838   3276827
4    4.5  NCMN7838  98567498
5    2.1  NCMN7838       NaN
```

And then if you really want to drop the zero values, you can keep only the nonzero ones using `fast_df = fast_df[fast_df['value'] != 0]`.